# Как запустить функцию заново, если выпадает исключение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, исключения, обработка-ошибок, повторы

> Дана функция с исключением внутри. если исключение не выпадает, то
> функция работает дальше.

Как запустить функцию заново, если исключение выпадает?

Comment: try:
        pass
    expect:
        def_name()

Comment: прямо в функции не стоит делать рекурсивный вызов, лучше сделайте обертку для этой функции,

т.е. вызываете обертку, в которой ловите исключение исходной функции.

Если исключение поймано - повторно выполняете вызов функции, если опять исключение - тогда кидаете его дальше.

А ловля исключения и рекурсия может привести к бесконечной рекрсии.

Как вариант - использовать рекурсию, но дополнительно передавать параметр-флаг (по дефолту False, при повторном вызове передаете True) - если параметр True, тогда не обрабатываете исключение, иначе повторный вызов функции

Comment: у себя (на php) я ожидал исключений, и давал несколько шансов выполниться функции, т.е. грубо код у меня был таким:

    def func():
        pass
    def wrapper():
        repeatCount = 10
        for i in xrange(repeatCount):
            try:
                func()
                break
            catch Exception, e:
                pass

Т.о. если функция кидала исключение, то выполнялся повторный ее вызов. Если опять было исключение - опять повторный вызов и так несколько раз. Только паузу между вызовами не забывайте делать, чтобы во время повторных вызовов не занимать процессорное время

Answer (score 6):

В коде:

- `try_repeat`  – декоратор, который повторяет вызов функции, если та выкинула исключение.
- `exception_func`  – функция, которая с вероятностью 50% выбросит исключение

Пример:

```
def try_repeat(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        count = 10

        while count:
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                print('Error:', e)
                count -= 1

    return wrapper


@try_repeat
def exception_func():
    import random
    if random.randint(0, 1):
        raise Exception('!!!')


exception_func()
```

Comment: стоит упомянуть, что использовать декоратор преждевременно в этом случае: требования в разных случаях самые разные могут быть (какие исключения ловить, сколько раз повторять и при каких условиях повторять, добавить паузу или сразу запускать, выполнять ли какие либо действия в случае исключения (помимо повтора) запись в лог итд. Код для каждого конкретного случая относительно несложно написать и читать—глядя на `try_repeat()` декоратор не ясно как эти опции выбраны, поэтому начинать нужно с самого простого кода, который решает задачу для рассматриваемого случая

Comment: ... и только в случае похожих требований в разных местах проекта, рассмотреть как можно код повторно использовать.

Answer (score 4):

```
u@net13:~> cat 000.py

#!/usr/bin/env python3

def input_val():
    try:
        a=int(input("Введите значение: "))
        print (a)
    except ValueError:
        print ("Требуется ввести числовое значение")
        input_val()
    else:
        print ("Отлично!")

input_val()
```

Будет выполняться до тех пор, пока не будет введено числовое значение.

Comment: Можно [явный цикл вместо рекурсии использовать](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/4279)